# How can I edit #text child node text value as element with beautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, web, beautifulsoup

I want to get every part of inner text of parsed `<p>` tag as *soup-element* with `beautifulSoup` in Python. I'm currently migrating the parser from php to Python. Here is some code on php and my attempt to translate the code using Python and `beautifulSoup`:

**PHP (this code works)**

```php
foreach($pTagNode->childNodes as $innerNode){
    if($innerNode->nodeName == "#text"){
        # Editing and parahrasing text part of <p> tag...
    }
    else if($innerNode->nodeName == "a"){
        # Do something with "a" tag, like removing blacklisted link or chaning text...
    }
}
```

**Python (this code doesn't work)**

```py
node = soup.select("p")[0]

# <a> tag
for pnode in node.select("a"):
    print("link found: " + pnode.string");
# <#text> tag
for pnode in node.select("#text"):
    print("text found: " + pnode.string) # This message doesnt shown :(
```

**HTML structure I want to parse:**

```html
<body>
    <p>Some text 1 and this is <a href="">the link</p>
    <p>Some text 2 and this is <a href="">the another link</p>
    <p>Some text 3 and this is <a href="">the link 3</p>
</body>
```

*I want to do something like this:*

```
[Some text 1 and this is ] = "My new link is "
[the link] = "here!"
```

I am looking for a way how I can **get** and **set** `#text` as an element. For example, php has `DomXPath` that allows you to do this. Does anyone have any ideas? If something else is needed, I can edit this question.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, this should get you there (or close):

```
list(soup.select_one('p').stripped_strings)
```

Output from the html in your question:

```
['Some text 1 and this is', 'the link']
```

Comment: Ye, that works. But I need to change text inside. I tried to do this with using your answer, but it doesnt work. `i = 0; while i < len(list(node.stripped_strings)): list(node.stripped_strings)[i] = "any val here"; i += 1; pass`

Comment: @cyberfrogg Well, in your question you said you want to get the text element, not to set it. And the same with your expected output. You should probably post this new issue as a separate question (per SO policy) and in there indicate exactly what the new output (with the `any val here`) should look like.